# Disabling quartz job in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using the [Quartz plugin](http://grails.org/Quartz+plugin) in Grails. Is there a configuration that I can use to disable the job, without commenting out or deleting the whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this functionality does not exist in the current version of Quartz. However there is a patch that implements job cancellation and rescheduling, so it seems plausible that it will be added to the official release in the (near?) future. See this [email thread](http://www.nabble.com/Dynamic-jobs-and-quartz-0.4-snapshot-td23386520.html) for details. If you want to try the patch yourself, it can be found on the [bug tracker](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1130).

Answer (score 2):

as a workaround, you could make the job check a configuration option, or query the DB, and just not do its thing if its not supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but how about adding a return statement as the first line in the execute() method?